# Extract session ID from psexec / PowerShell query user command

Tags: session, powershell, rdp, psexec

I'm writing a PowerShell script to find out the session ID of the active user at a remote machine, to then launch a program using that session ID. Here is what I have so far.

```
$queryusers = $psexecdirectory + ' \\' +  $remotepc + ' -u ' + $domain + '\' + $username + ' -p ' + $password + ' query user'
$results = iex $queryusers
```

The above works fine, with the example results below being stored on the variable `$results`

```
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
 usr1                              3  Disc         1:12  9/5/2013 11:59
AM
>usr2          rdp-tcp#1           4  Active          .  9/5/2013 11:59
AM
```

I've used the below to get the ID, but the number on session name 'rdp-ctp#0' changes when another user logs in, like in the output above, rendering it useless:

```
$id = $results | Select-String "$rdp-tcp#0\s+(\w+)" |
                 Foreach {$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value}
```

I am unfamiliar with the PowerShell syntax, and have been unable to find a site where formatting options are explained. Can someone help me out? And if you know of a website where I can learn more about extracting snippets from strings? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Or use more powershell (WMI actually) and you don't need psexec nor string fiddeling. http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/0e43993a-895a-4afe-a2b2-045a5146048a

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$id = $results | ? { $_ -match '(\d+)\s+Active' } | % { $matches[1] }
```

The regular expression `(\d+)\s+Active` will match the keyword "Active" preceeded by a number and the subsequent loop returns the first submatch (i.e. the number).

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you. I'll make sure to read about regular expressions.